# SQL 1000+ values and VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

```
WITH
    part_set
    AS
        (
        select p.part_id from parts p where p.part_id in (1231,1235,67567,35,373,1000)
Union
        select p.part_id from parts p where p.part_id in (12345,1234,123,123455,1000)
```

I have 300,000 part_id's to query, since SQL will only accept up to 1000 values I created the With and Union clause in SQL above. Is there a way to write VBA to wrap the select statement around the part id's in excel? I have the list of part Id's in excel. I'm open to any suggestions that would not force me to copy and paste 300 times.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't load the values from Excel into a table in Oracle (potentially a temp table) and then just join to that or use that in the `IN` clause?  That's going to be vastly easier than programmatically assembling a statement that has 300,000 literal `part_id` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use excel formulas for each parts.
This is example for first row:

```
="select p.part_id from parts p where p.part_id in (" & $A1 & "," & $B1 & "," & $C1 & "," & $D1 & "," & $E1 & "," & $F1 & ")" & CHAR(10) & " union"
```

When you have created first formula you can use autofill function for all rows.
After that, you will receive a list of all selected